# How to achieve grid layout logic to follow a specific pattern for every alternating rows? Responsive to be kept in mind too

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

[image: Desired grid layout]

---

I am creating this layout using a grid container. This is for a blog list, which means more blogs (cards) can be added.
There are 3 kinds of cards according to the design. (varying image sizes)

---

Method I have in my mind:
Define separate classes for each card and span them accordingly and use grid-auto-flow as dense.
Reference: [auto-placement](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

---

Is there a better way to do this?
I followed [this document](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) to understand about grids.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/exploring-css-grids-implicit-grid-and-auto-placement-powers/

Comment: @TemaniAfif thankyou. I'll read the document and update my progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea to start with.
Codepen: https://codepen.io/brandonzhang/pen/QWxaEPQ

```html
<section class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #234;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  gap: 1rem;
}

div {
  background: lightseagreen;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div:nth-child(5n+1) {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

div:nth-child(5n+2) {
  grid-column: 6 / -1;
}

div:nth-child(5n+3),
div:nth-child(5n+4),
div:nth-child(5n+5)
{
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I did something similar tho. I generalized it a bit more. (I made a 12 column grid with gap of 20px, styled all the default grid items to span 4 cols and used nth child to style the remaining two card sizes using 5n+1 and 5n+2). I loved solving this problem.